# SQL Find Similar Names in Same Column

Tags: sql

I'm doing a data cleanup & have a [Prospects] column that has data such as:

`ProspectA - 2013
ProspectA - 2015
ProsB.2014
ProsB.2015
2013xyz
2014xyz
2015xyz
abc
Prospect2
George`

Now I want to return groups of prospects, i.e. if part of prospect matches another prospect, return those groups. In this example, I would return:

`ProspectA - 2013
ProspectA - 2015
ProsB.2014
ProsB.2015
2013xyz
2014xyz
2015xyz`

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a form of the "Like" operator to distinguish between the things you want and you can order them by descending as well

```
SELECT * FROM [table]
WHERE [field] LIKE '%Pros'
ORDER BY [desired field name]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I thought of that, however not all start with 'Pros' (see 2013xyz). I also thought of using CHARINDEX & creating a table using WITH, however not quite sure how to link those up.

Answer (score 0):

Hear is the solution. It only works for those string which has same character and different numbers.

```
select * from table_name t
      where REGEXP_REPLACE(t.name,'[0-9]','') in 
                   (select REGEXP_REPLACE(name1,'[0-9]','')  from table_name
                           where rowid<>t.rowid
                   )
```